# Intellij Idea: Error in deploying to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I have recently switched to Idea version 2017 and when I try to deploy to Google App Engine, it gives the error: "Error running Google App Engine deployment: Server not specified"

[image: Error screenshot]

I think there was a new setting in this version (asking for a server name). I left it empty in my first attempt and now that dialog doesn't popup and straightaway gives this error every time.

How can I remove the stored settings of this App Engine plugin, so that it'll as the server name again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke this action for the first time IntelliJ IDEA just creates a new Run/Debug configuration for the Google App Engine. You can always access it later in the [Edit Run/Debug configurations dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) and change the server and/or the artifact to deploy:

[image: Edit run/debug configuration]

Comment: Thank you. I thought it would be like a "change of deployment related credentials" where you had to invalidate the credentials stored somewhere by removing the "user" entry from the IML file. Found the Run/Debug configuration, fixed up the server and able to deploy now. Thanks.